# HQL for the simple SQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have the below query that is ..

```
SELECT * FROM POS_took WHERE DELETEDDATE IS NOTNULL
```

I have corresponding pojo....

```
class postook
{

//all the properties defined here 

private DateTime deleted;

//and it corresponding setters and egetters is defined.
```

Please advise the corresponding hql , what I have tried is shown below but it is not rite one also..

```
session.createQuery("from postook where deleted is notnull")
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `from postook pok where pok.deleted is not null`. But the error you get should make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
session.createQuery("from postook where deleted is not null") (add space between NOT and NULL)
```

Idem for your SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM POS_took WHERE DELETEDDATE IS NOT NULL
```